# Subscribers receive messages slowly

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, pyzmq

I have a pyzmq Publisher which sends around 1000 messages per second. I am trying to start around 10 Subscribers in an asyncio event_loop.

It works but around 2.5 times slower than speed of the only one Subscriber.

What could possibly be wrong with the code?

```
import asyncio
import zmq
import json
from zmq.backend.cython.constants import NOBLOCK
from zmq.asyncio import Context, Poller
from loop_ import Loop


class Client:
    REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 35000
    SERVER_ENDPOINT = "tcp://localhost:6666"

    def __init__(self, id_):
        self.id = id_

    def get_task(self):
        return asyncio.create_task(self.client_coroutine())

    async def client_coroutine(self):
        context = Context.instance()

        socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        socket.connect(self.SERVER_ENDPOINT)
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'4')
        poller = Poller()
        poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)

        while True:
            event = dict(await poller.poll(self.REQUEST_TIMEOUT))
            if event.get(socket) == zmq.POLLIN:
                reply = await socket.recv_multipart(flags=NOBLOCK)
                if not reply:
                    break
                else:
                    print(eval(json.loads(reply[1].decode('utf-8'))))
            else:
                print("No response from server, retrying...")
                socket.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
                socket.close()
                poller.unregister(socket)

async def tasks():
    _tasks = [Client(id_).get_task() for id_ in range(10)]
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(_tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(tasks())
```

Comment: What is in the `loop_` module?

Comment: Why do you create a new thread and event loop per client? The event loop is normally a singleton, and one event loop can service all async needs of the application. (Think of it like JavaScript's event loop implicit to the run-time.) You technically **can** create create multiple event loops, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea because then you can't mix and match futures from different event loops, because accessing results requires glue code like `run_coroutine_threadsafe` (which adds some overhead), and because any housekeeping coroutines created by zmq need to be created for each loop.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I didn't now that it's not good idea. I copied the loop_ module from another project where I used one event_loop per WebSocket from websockets library. Each WebSocket object creates some tasks during the work and after reconnection i had memory leak after some time. I realized later that there were not closed task after reconnection. I decided to close the loop which serves that socket and create a new one to connect again. I've just updated the code but the problem repeats again.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. The question appears to be about the existing code being inefficient. Did you try benchmarking with a single event loop?

Comment: Yes, I did. It still works slowly.

Comment: Please update the question with the simpler single-threaded version. The less code in the question, the more chance that someone will spot the issue.

Comment: I've changed the code. Now it works 5 times faster than previous version but i need to gather data from Subscribers and make some not async calculations how can I do this with the one thread?

Comment: If you need to run sync code (which could take a while), use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor). It will submit the function to a thread pool and transfer the result back to async when it's done. The advantage is that only sync code runs in threads, and you don't have multiple event loops for the async stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Q** : *What could possibly be wrong with the code?*

Given the code is using the same **`localhost`** ( as seen from using the address ), the suspect number one is, that having 10x more work to process, the such workload will always stress the `localhost`'s O/S and the CPU, won't it?

Next comes the choice of the transport-class. Given all the **`SUB`**-s are co-located on the same **`localhost`** as the **`PUB`**, there is all the L3-stack-based TCP/IP protocol work going wasted. To compare the relative costs ( the add-on effect of using the **`tcp://`** transport-class for this hardware-singular messaging ), test the very same with using **`inproc://`** transport-class, where none of the protocol-related TCP/IP-stack add-on processing will take place.

Last, but not least, my code will never mix different event-loops ( using ZeroMQ since v2.11, so someone may consider my a bit old-fashioned in avoiding relying on `async`-decorated capabilities available in recent py3.6+ )

My code will use an explicit, non-blocking, zero-waiting test for a presence of a message per-`aSocketINSTANCE`, as in **`aSocketINSTANCE.poll( zmq.POLLIN, 0 )`** rather than using any "externally" added decoration, which may report the same, but via some additional (expensive and outside of my code domain of control) event-handling. All real-time, low-latency use-cases strive to bear as minimum latency/overheads as possible, so using explicit control will always win in my Projects, to any "modern" syntax-sugar sweetened tricks.

Anyway, enjoy the Zen-of-Zero

Comment: Thank you for your valued comment! I've changed the tcp:// transport-class to the ipc:// transport-class (because I run publisher and subscribers separately) and now subscribers receive messages almost as fast as publisher sends them. There was a small problem with lacking of the last messages which I hadn't had when I had used the tcp:// transport-class but after setting zmq.RCVBUF bigger it starts working as expected. Could you clarify please the last passage. If I want to use aSocketINSTANCE.poll(...) should I zmq.async.Context().instance().socket(...) to create a socket?

Comment: Glad to hear it helped to solve the issue. StackOverflow encourages users to click +1 for situations there is something useful or interesting in either a Question or Answer, to reflect such usefulness - **do not hesitate to follow this Netiquette - *it is a rule, how the StackOverflow Community works***

Comment: If you have more questions, feel free to **Accept** the best Answer provided for your Question and open another one, specific to your new views or here inspired further steps in experimentations. ***This is how the StackOverflow Community works* - do not hesitate to comply with it.**

Comment: @user3666197 I did it. +1